# How to get Current Project Directory path using C#

Tags: c#, .net

okay, here is the question. I have two projects one is C# Console and other is Class library.
I am accessing/calling Class library method from the console app.
There is a folder called Files within the class library project.

I need to get the path of the Class library's files folder but whenever I use

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

and

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

it is giving me path of the Console project which I am using to call the method.

Above methods are giving me path like

```
C:\\ConsolePro\\bin\\Debug
```

but I need the path of Class library project

```
C:\\ClassLibPro\\bin\\Debug
```

Please advise

Comment: FYI you will never get the path of the dll directory as Visual Studio will copy the dependencies from their original location (ClassLibPro) to the bin / debug folder of your project (Console Pro).  There is no way to trace this back during run time.

Comment: Why do you need the path of the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is:

Since the Console project has the DLL file reference it is using DLL to call any methods.
At this time it is returning the class library projct's DLL location which is located in console project's bin directory and it doesn't know about the physical location of class library project.

so essentially it is returning the same project path. I will have to move both projects in same directory in order to solve this issue.

Answer (score 11):

Once the code is compiled and running, 'Project Path' has no meaning. All you can determine are the file locations of the compiled assemblies. And you can only do what you are asking if your Console project references the built 'class library' DLL directly, rather than via a Project Reference.

Then, you can make use of Reflection to get Assembly paths like;

```
string path = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (SomeClassInOtherProject)).Location;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` a few times to get higher level directories and then add the path of the lib directory to the end of that.

Comment: No, this is not the answer. I need to know how I can get the current project's path where my file is located. Please read the question again!

Comment: It worked for me, to get a more higher level directories, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

If you loading the class library from another assembly.

```
string Path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof({LibraryClassName})).Location;

string PathToClassLibPro = Path.GetDirectoryName( Path);
```

Replace `{LibraryClassName}` with the class name of your library.

Comment: This doesn't work. Path is coming as the DLL which is located with in console project.

Comment: How to define the assembly type at the place of {assembly}. I am using like this  string Path=System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

Comment: Which class name did you use? your library project class? Why didnt it work, wrong path?

Comment: Check my answer. I have explained in it. Your code does returns location but the DLL location which is in the Console project. so essentially it is returning the same project path. I will have to move both projects in same directory in order to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand u corretly:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Foo.MyFooClass).Assembly.Location);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend one of two options.

1. If the files are small include them in the class library and stream them to a temp location when needed
2. Other option is to copy the files during the build to the output directory and use them that way.  In cases of multiple shared projects it is best to have a common bin folder that you copy assemblies to and run from that location.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following approach to get the current project path at runtime:

```
public static class ProjectInfo {
   public static string appDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
   public static string projectPath = appDirectory.Substring(0, appDirectory.IndexOf("\\bin"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue as well where I couldn't access the file in my namespace's bin/debug folder. My solution was to manipulate the string using `Split()` then construct a new string which is the absolute path to the json file I have in my namespace.

```
private static string GetFilePath()
        {            
            const char Escape = '\\'; //can't have '\' by itself, it'll throw the "Newline in constant" error
            string directory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string[] pathOccurences = directory.Split(Escape);            
            string pathToReturn = pathOccurences[0] + Escape; //prevents index out of bounds in upcoming loop
            for(int i = 1; i < pathOccurences.Length; i++)
            {
                if (pathOccurences[i] != pathOccurences[i - 1]) //the project file name and the namespace file name are the same
                    pathToReturn += pathOccurences[i] + Escape;
                else
                    pathToReturn += typeof(thisClass).Namespace + Escape; //In the one occurrence of the duplicate substring, I replace it with my class Namespace name
            }
            return pathToReturn + "yourFile.json";
        }
```

I personally don't like this solution, but it was the only answer I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Despite i cant find a good solution i use this trick : 
as long as you want to come back to your ideal path u should add **Directory.GetParent()** instead of **...**

```
  Directory.GetParent(...(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).ToString()...).ToString()
```