# XDocument.load(string uri) throws ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, argumentnullexception, system.xml

I get an ArgumentNullException when calling

```
string filepath = @"AppData\TestAppData.xml";
        if (filepath != null)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filepath); 
        }
```

Here are the exception details. It says, that the "format" parameter is null - but at which point am I able to control this parameter?
Or what exactly is my mistake?

```
> System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Message=Value cannot be null.
>     Parameter name: format
>     ParamName=format
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>        at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format,   ParamsArray args)
>        at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
>        at System.SR.Format(String resourceFormat, Object[] args)
>        at System.Xml.XmlException.CreateMessage(String res, String[] args, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition)
>        at System.Xml.XmlException..ctor(String res, String[] args, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, String
> sourceUri)
>        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
>        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributeValueSlow(Int32 curPos, Char quoteChar, NodeData attr)
>        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
>        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
>        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
>        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
>        at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
>        at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
>        at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
>        at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
>        at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri)
```

Comment: Looks like invalid XML.

Comment: However, it shouldn't be throwing a null ref exception from that level of the code...

Comment: Agreed, looks like an XML error severe enough to trip the parser before it can make a decent report.

Comment: @redGreen - try to open the XML file in Visual Studio or another editor. See if you can get an error report that way.

Comment: yeah. thanks! that solved it :) a closing tag was missing..

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
string EnviromentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath);
```

to get the path to your project directory
and then you should combine them after that

```
Path.Combine(EnviromentPath,@"AppData\TestAppData.xml");
```

Comment: No, a wrong path would not result in a NullRef exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: [How I use XDocument.Load() to get a file in the application directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680386/how-i-use-xdocument-load-to-get-a-file-in-the-application-directory)

It seems the filepath is not correct, try this

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
```

Comment: A missing or otherwise unopenable file yields a different exception.