# Loading an object to XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have an *.xml file that I have added to my solution and set it's build action to "Resource". I want to load its contents into a `List<string>`.

I found out I can access the file with `ResourceManager` (after numerous tries I concluded it's impossible to access it in another way).

But `XDocument.Load` requires an Uri, which I have no idea what it is for my file, because it doesn't work with what I've read on other questions and MSDN.

Here is a picture of my solution structure, pertaining to the file:
[image: Da filez] (I need "ServerList.xml")

I tried using the following Uris:

- ServerList.xml
- \ServerList.xml
- Data\ServerList.xml
- \Data\ServerList.xml
- /ServerList.xml
- Data/ServerList.xml
- /Data/ServerList.xml

None of them work.
This code, does, somewhat:

```
var rm = new ResourceManager("SQLExecutor.g", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var rset = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true, true);
var obj = SerializeToStream rset.GetObject(@"data/serverlist.xml", true);
```

So, now, `obj` is an object but I need either an Uri or a Stream to pass to `XDocument.Load`. I actually just need to get the information out of the *.xml and am only using XDocument, because I think it would be best, but am having problems serializing `obj`.

So what, exactly, should I do in order to be able to load this "ServerList.xml" file in an XDocument, so I can work with it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18680852/7974050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18680852/7974050, if that suits your purpose.

Alternatively, you can

Set the file Build Action to *Embedded Resource*. Suppose, xml file is in root directory of your application. Now, when you build your solution, it will get embedded in the dll.

```
    You can get this data in 

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(GetResourceTextFile("postdata.xml")));
```

and then load this reader in XDocument.

```
    public string GetResourceTextFile(string filename)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        //  In the code below, replace xyz. with the name of your dll + .
        // (dot). Idea is to treat file like dllName.filename.xml
        using (Stream stream = this.GetType().Assembly.
                   GetManifestResourceStream("xyz." + filename))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```